# Lithium: How Document->save() or Record->save() works

Tags: lithium

In lithium,  document and record classes, or their superclasses/interfaces, have no save() method. Yet lithium's method for saving the record is as follows:

```
$record = Model::create()
$record->save()
```

I am not certain how this works, since record does not have save method (only Model has).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document` and `Record` extend from a base `Entity` class.  The `Entity` class has a `__call()` [magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).  See the api doc for `Entity::__call` over here: [http://li3.me/docs/lithium/data/Entity::__call()](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/data/Entity%3a%3a__call%28%29)  That method obtains an instance of the `Model` class associated with the `Entity` and then calls the method passing the entity object in as the first argument.  The [Adding Functions To Models](http://li3.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/adding-functions-to-models.wiki) section of the Lithium manual also contains additional info related to this.